# Buffer Overrun c++ , thread has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am working with c++ and Visual Studio 2012. I am getting this error, thread has exited with code 0 (0x0).

```
int deckCopy[208]; //will be used for the purpose of shuffling
int index = 0; //will be used to keep track of indexs of the array and to shuffle

//fills the array deck by deck
for(int y = 0; y <= 4; y++){
    for(int i = 0; i < 13; i ++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 4; x ++){
            deckCopy[index] = ((1 + i) * 10) + (x + 1);
            index ++;
        }
    }
}

//shuffle the deck
for(int i = 0; i < 208; i ++){
    do{
        index = rand() % 208;
        cout << deckCopy[index];
        deckRank[i] = deckCopy[index] / 10;
        deckSuit[i] = deckCopy[index] % 10;
    }while(deckRank[i]  == 0);
    deckCopy[index] = 0;
}
```

visual studio recommends the I search for 'How to debug buffer overrun issues', however nothing I find relates to what is happening. Using the debugger, I narrowed it down to

```
deckRank[i] = deckCopy[index] / 10;
```

I have no idea why this could be happening, and it happens on the first iteration. If anyone could explain why this is happening or offer a solution that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The error happened just a bit before that first line, in the previous loop nest.  You're going through 5 decks here, not 4:

```
for(int y = 0; y <= 4; y++){
```

I think you meant:

```
for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
```

Also, your shuffle routine, while it will work, will run very slowly.  You should look up the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) technique, or use [`std::shuffle<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) if you're allowed to use the C++ standard algorithms.

Comment: I did mean that. Whoops. Do you think that would have caused the issue? And we are not allowed to use standard algorithms.

Comment: @user3078918 :  Well, you should still be able to write your own Fisher-Yates shuffle or something like it.  Your current shuffle will get very slow near the end of the 4-deck shuffle, as it randomly picks a value 0 .. 207 over and over until it finally finds the last cards...

Comment: That did seem to fix the problem, and I think I will write my own Fisher-Yates shuffle.